# Regexp for content inside tags

Tags: javascript, regex, strip-tags

I use **Javascript**
I have this:

```
<(div|span) class="search-result-(body-text|title)">(.*?)</(span|div)>
```

And i use is on this content:

```
<div class="search-result-item club">
   <span class="search-result-type">Projekt</span
   <span class="search-result-title">Titel</span>
   <div class="search-result-body-text">
     Body text
   </div>
   <div class="search-result-attributes">
     <span class="search-result-attribute">Attribute</span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

My result is:

```
<span class="search-result-title">Titel</span>,
<div class="search-result-body-text">
  Body text
</div>
```

**Thats make sense, but how should my regexp look like so it strips the tags, so i only get:** *Titel*, *Body text*

Comment: Regex implementations vary. What language are you using?

Answer (score 4):

It is required by law that someone post a link to this: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) which you should read and reconsider whether you *really* want to be parsing HTML using regular expressions.

However, what you want is the contents of the third () group in your match. The `exec` method of a JS regular expression object is an array containing the whole match at index 0, and the matches from all the groups at indices 1,2,... (in this case index 3 is what you need).

[NOTE: an earlier version of this answer had "first" and "1" instead of "third" and "3" above, because I misread your regexp. Sorry.]

Comment: This is a search string result that i get, and i want to hightlight the content in title and body..so i have good control over what im parsing..